# changing multiple cell colors based on one cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to change the color in cells A3 to A9 if the value in cell A7 is 'Locked'.
so far I'm only able to change the value in cell A7.
Can someone help with my code?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim myrange As Range
Set myrange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A3:A8")
For Each cell In myrange
If cell.Value Like "STBT" Then
cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
ElseIf cell.Value Like "Locked" Then
cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
Else: cell.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Is the sheet where the above event is triggered `Sheet1`? Do you really want changing the colors in case of **any selection on the respective sheet**? If so, may I know why? Shouldn't you use `Change` event being triggered by a change in that specific range?

Comment: The event is triggered in Sheet1 - it's a bit mickey-mouse, but the purpose of the sheet is to indicate to warehousemen whether or not a trailer is locked out. Cell A3:A6 are merged, cell A7 indicates the locked status, cell A8 is the loading sequence. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Not really... If any cell of the respective range **is not changed** why running a piece of code not modifying anything?

Answer (score 0):

According to your question, code would look like

```
Dim myrange As Range

Set myrange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A3:A9") 

'Change the color in cells A3 to A9 if the value in cell A7 is Locked
If Range("A7").Value Like "Locked" Then 
    myrange.Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
End If
```